# mysql load data local infile

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load data into a mysql table using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE using the code below.

Mysql:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/test1.csv' INTO TABLE temp_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (recloc,client_acc)
```

Edit: changed LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to LOADA DATA INFILE, removed SET id=null, added IGNORE 1 LINES

I'm getting no errors and no imported records.  I believe the issue is related to the column names but i'm having a hard time fully understanding what those names should be. Should they be the actual column names within the CSV? or the field names in the DB Table? I would also like the have an auto_incremented primary key (id).

CSV:

```
recloc,client_acc
"NLGSX3","CORPORATE"
"7SC3BA","QUALITY ASSURANCE"
"3B9OHF","90717-6710"
```

Any suggestions to what I may be doing wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names in CSV are not necessary, so you should add `IGNORE 1 LINES` clause.

Columns in your query `(recloc,client_acc)` need to match columns in table. 
First column from CSV will be inserted into `recloc`, second into `client_acc`.

If you don't specifu AUTO_INCREMENT column in the statement, but there is one in the table, it should fill automatically.

Comment: "IGNORE 1 LINES" added, removed "SET id=null", Still no luck. I'm also storing the CSV in the directory of the import script but i've also tried the server path. Shouldn't I be getting some kind of mysql error?

Comment: After more research i changed LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to LOAD DATA INFILE since i'm using files stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet solution for excel to mysql data import:

Working good for txt file formats.
IN DETAIL:

```
tbl name=t1
feilds are= name varchar,email varchar;
```

text.txt file  <<== this text file first lines table column names:

```
name,   email
"n1",   "e1"  next line 
"n2",   "e2" next line 
"n3",   "e3" next line 
"n4",   "e4" next line 
"n5",   "e5" next line 
"n6",   "e6" next line 
"n7",   "e7" next line
```

pls ignore next line statements
SQL query in wamp

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/wamp/www/touch/text.txt' INTO TABLE t1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES(name,email)
```

For this commnad run successfully we have create folders for separately.

Real one is

C:\wamp\mysql\data\wamp\www\touch\text.txt <<==pysical file path is.

But we mention c:/wamp/touch/text.txt