# Table `generic_table_name` doesn't exist using 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' for MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm under the impression that this command will create a table for you. Is this the wrong idea? I have this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/michael/WebstormProjects/d3_graphs_with_node/public/DFData/ADWORDS_AD_DATA.csv'
INTO TABLE ADWORDS_AD_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(campaign_id,adgroup_id,ad_group,campaign,account,week,keyword,keyword_state,match_type,max_cpc,clicks,impressions,ctr,avg_cpc,avg_cpm,cost,avg_position,quality_score,first_page_cpc,first_position_cpc,converted_clicks,click_conversion_rate,cost_converted_click,cost_all_conv,total_conv_value,conversions,cost_conv,conv_rate)
```

I counted the columns and there is 28 and I made exactly 28 entries after `IGNORE 1 LINES`. I looked at these SO posts and tried to follow the syntax outlined by the MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Any ideas?

[mysql-load-local-infile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441711/mysql-load-data-local-infile)

[import-csv-to-mysql-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table)

Comment: You are under the wrong impression.  This command *loads* data into an existing table.  It is analogous to `insert` with a file.

Comment: So would I have to manually make a table with 28 columns with their respective column types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay manually added table and set the column names and it worked!

A side note, I had 2 versions of MySQL running and that was also giving me confusion as to why the table/database I created in phpmyadmin wasn't showing up in the MySQL shell in the command line.
[MAMP MYSQL vs system MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335403/access-mamps-mysql-from-terminal)